# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error in asp.net core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a task in `asp.net core 2.2` which is called eventually on specific condition which is this

```
private async Task calculateChatDuration (string id) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("in chat duration helper : "+id);
    try {
        Console.WriteLine("in try block");
        var convObject = DbService.conversations.Find (new BsonDocument ("_id", new ObjectId(id))).FirstOrDefault ();
        Console.WriteLine("conv object : " + convObject);
        Console.WriteLine("nsp : "+convObject["nsp"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("email : "+convObject["agentEmail"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("date : "+Convert.ToDateTime (convObject["createdOn"].ToString()));

        ChatDuration chatduration = new ChatDuration();
        chatduration.nsp = convObject["nsp"].ToString ();
        chatduration.convIDs.Add(id);
        chatduration.agentEmail = convObject["agentEmail"].ToString ();
        chatduration.date = Convert.ToDateTime (convObject["createdOn"].ToString ());
        TimeSpan difference = Convert.ToDateTime (convObject["endingDate"].ToString ()).ToUniversalTime () - Convert.ToDateTime (convObject["createdOn"].ToString ()).ToUniversalTime ();
        Console.WriteLine("time difference : "+difference.TotalMinutes);
        chatduration.duration = Convert.ToDouble (difference.TotalMinutes);
        Console.WriteLine ("inserting jobect in end : " + chatduration.ToJson());
        await DbService.warehouse_chatduration.InsertOneAsync(chatduration);
        Console.WriteLine ("-- document inserted (chatduration to warehouse) --");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine ("Error in Inserting (chatduration to warehouse)");
    }
}
```

The problem is this when this `task` called so it prints till

```
Console.WriteLine("date : "+Convert.ToDateTime (convObject["createdOn"].ToString()));
```

And throws an error at

```
ChatDuration chatduration = new ChatDuration();
```

It throws this error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Here is `class` definition

```
 public class ChatDuration 
 {
    public BsonObjectId _id {get; set;}
    public string nsp {get; set;}
    public string agentEmail {get; set;}
    public double duration {get; set;}
    public DateTime date {get; set;}
    public BsonArray convIDs {get; set;}

 }
```

Here is the console results i am getting

[image: like this]
What's the error in this code?

Comment: No, this is not the answer for me

Comment: What do you think would happen if `convObject["createdOn"]` returned `null`?

Comment: But in my case it is printing this `Console.WriteLine("date : "+Convert.ToDateTime (convObject["createdOn"].ToString()));` that means `convObject["createdOn"]` is not returning null

Comment: Your problem description stated that it prints "till" (which means until but not including). If it does print that line and that value is not null then you need to include the stack trace of the exception in your above question.

Comment: @Igor there is no stack trace is coming on console. I am just receiving this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: All exceptions have a stack trace. See also the marked duplicate for further help or google how to get a stack trace from an exception (it is a property of System.Exception).

Comment: @Igor you can see in my code that i used proper `try` and `catch` block and also prints `Exception` message but still i am not getting exception stack trace.

Comment: You can also print out an exception using `.ToString()` which will include the stack trace as well as nested exception information.

Comment: `.Message` only gets the message, this omits all the "good" details about the exception including the stack trace and any nested excption information. I would recommend you do a little reading on exception handling best practices.

Comment: So if i will do like `ex.Message.ToString()` so will it not give me proper stack trace?

Comment: Just `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: i tried it `Just ex.ToString()` but stil i am only getting this message `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`